# question on chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I have a function $v(a_t, q_t)$ and the objective function is $\sum_t {v(a_t, q_t)}$
Here, q evolves according to $q_{t+1} = a_t + q_t$, and the cross-partial $v_{aq}(.)$ is positive, so  $a_{t+1}$ is affected by a change in $a_t$ through $q_{t+1}$ as well.
Now, I want to take the derivative of my objective function with respect to $a_t$.
Suppose the end period T = 2. I am having troubles with seeing the following:

$\frac{\partial v (a_{t+2}, q_{t+2})}{\partial a_t} \neq \frac{\partial v }{\partial a_{t+2}}\frac{\partial a_{t+2} }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t+1}}\frac{\partial a_{t+1} }{\partial q_{t+1}}\frac{\partial q_{t+1} }{\partial a_{t}} + 
\frac{\partial v }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t+1}}\frac{\partial a_{t+1} }{\partial q_{t+1}}\frac{\partial q_{t+1} }{\partial a_{t}}$

But actually
$\frac{\partial v (a_{t+2}, q_{t+2})}{\partial a_t} = \frac{\partial v }{\partial a_{t+2}}\frac{\partial a_{t+2} }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t}} + 
\frac{\partial v }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t}}
$ 
since $q_{t+2}$ is a function of $(a_{t+1}, q_{t+1})$ which implies it is a function of $(\frac{\partial a_{t+1}}{q_{t+1}}\frac{q_{t+1}}{a_t}, (q_t + a_t))$

My question is why 
$\frac{\partial v }{\partial a_{t+2}}\frac{\partial a_{t+2} }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t+1}}\frac{\partial a_{t+1} }{\partial q_{t+1}}\frac{\partial q_{t+1} }{\partial a_{t}} + 
\frac{\partial v }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t+1}}\frac{\partial a_{t+1} }{\partial q_{t+1}}\frac{\partial q_{t+1} }{\partial a_{t}} \neq 
\frac{\partial v }{\partial a_{t+2}}\frac{\partial a_{t+2} }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t}} + 
\frac{\partial v }{\partial q_{t+2}}\frac{\partial q_{t+2} }{\partial a_{t}}$ ??

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{t+1}=f(a_t)$. Then,

\begin{equation}
v(a_2,q_2)=v(f(f(a_0)),f(a_0)+a_0+q_0).
\end{equation}

If we calculate the total derivative of the above function with respect to $a_0$, it should be

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{da_0}v(f(f(a_0)),f(a_0)+a_0+q_0)\\
=\frac{\partial v(a_2,q_2)}{\partial a_2}\cdot f'(a_1)\cdot f'(a_0)+\frac{\partial v(a_2,q_2)}{\partial q_2}\cdot (f'(a_0)+1).
\end{equation}

I don't quite understand what you mean with your algebra.

Comment: Thank you user495799 for pointing that out. Yes, I did forgot to mention that I just wanted to focus on the first term of v(.), but I should have been precise in the first place anyways. I edited my question.

So I follow your algebra up there, but I think what is confusing here is that $a_{t+1}$ is affected by a change in $a_t$ only through $q_{t+1}$, and thus one has to follow a successive chain rule. Am I clarifying my point?